# jQuery DataTables - Re-Order Columns from ColVis dropdown

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables with ColVis + ReOrder Table Columns

How can do the following?

- From ColVis dropdown I have to re-order columns
- Once I re-order from the dropdown, same re-order should appear in actual column as well...

---

### [Online Example](http://cssdeck.com/labs/ixe8oouo)

---

I have tried with jQuery Droppable plugin along with this.. but no luck...

> **Script**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'RC<"clear">lfrtip',
        columnDefs: [
            { visible: false, targets: 1 }
        ]
     });

    $(".ColVis_collection").sortable();

} );
```

Comment: So, basically you want the `ColVis` column list to behave as the `ColReorder` plugin? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? How do you think this could be achieved, what directions?

Comment: Hi **@davidkonrad**... tried with jQuery Droppable plugin but no luck... as I am not that great at jQuery, can somebody help me please?